# Can not find "Spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled" property in CDH 5.4.7 UI

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I can not find the `Spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` property in CDH 5.4.7 UI. I have searched the configuration of both the Spark and YARN services. But failed to locate. I am using Spark 1.3.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in `/etc/spark/conf.cloudera.spark_on_yarn/spark-defaults.conf` over CLI[image]

Comment: Is it available in the UI?

Comment: It is available in CDH 5.7, not sure about CDH 5.4